# Difference filter not working in Ansible

Tags: ansible

I am trying to find which ports are available for my use. The logic goes like this, I am firs  finding the used ports and providing a list of ports that I can use, the difference filter should filter out the ones that are available, but somehow it is not working.

Here is the code block:

```
- name: Gather occupied tcp v4 ports
  shell: netstat -nlt| awk '{print $4}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'
  register: used_ports
- debug:
        var: used_ports
- name: Difference
  vars:
    allowed_ports:
      - 107
      - 823
      - 4750
  set_fact:
        bind_port: "{{ allowed_ports | difference(used_ports) | first }}"
- name: Show bind port
  debug:
       var: bind_port
```

Output:

> ok: [] => {
>       "used_ports": {
>           "changed": true,
>           "cmd": "netstat -nlt| awk '{print $4}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'",
>           "delta": "0:00:00.077467",
>           "end": "2018-08-12 15:25:04.477710",
>           "failed": false,
>           "rc": 0,
>           "start": "2018-08-12 15:25:04.400243",
>           "stderr": "",
>           "stderr_lines": [],
>           "stdout": ",
>           "stdout_lines": [
>               "",
>               "",
>               "107",
>               "202",
>               "106"
>           ]
>       } }
>
> TASK [serverbuild : Difference]
>   ********************************************************************* ok: []
>
> TASK [serverbuild : Show bind port]
>   ***************************************************************** ok: [] => {
>       "bind_port": "107" }

Ideally it should not show 107 as it is already used. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You should replace `netstat -nlt| awk '{print $4}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'` by `netstat -nlt| awk '{print $4}'|awk -F':' '{print $2}'| grep -v '^$'` to trim empty lines.

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems:

1. You should use `used_ports.stdout_lines` as an argument to the `difference` filter,
2. You should either define `allowed_ports` to contain strings, or map `used_ports.stdout_lines` to integers.

So:

```
- name: Difference
  vars:
    allowed_ports:
      - "107"
      - "823"
      - "4750"
  set_fact:
    bind_port: "{{ allowed_ports | difference(used_ports.stdout_lines) | first }}"
```

or:

```
- name: Difference
  vars:
    allowed_ports:
      - 107
      - 823
      - 4750
  set_fact:
    bind_port: "{{ allowed_ports | difference(used_ports.stdout_lines|map('int')) | first }}"
```

Comment: This solution worked perfect for me. i added used_ports.stdout_lines and mapped them to integer.. thank you!!